# CSV reader inserts brackets in text

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to read a CSV file (i.e. a simple table) using python's `csv` module and create a dictionary where the first column is the key and the second column is the value. My problem is that when I parse each row/line, the text from the second column gets formatted with brackets.

For example, assume that the pipes separate each column of the table:

City | Number

Houston | 1

Austin | 2

Dallas | 3

(Sorry for the poor formatting, but I couldn't figure out how to get Stack Overflow to format tables correctly, even after trying.)

My code is:

```
my_dict = defaultdict(list)
with open(my_file, newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(csv_reader)  # Skip the row containing the column headers
    for row in csv_reader:
        region_name, region_code = row[0], int(row[1])
        my_dict[region_name].append(region_code)
```

When I print `my_dict`, I see that "Houston" has value [1], and not 1. I also see that "Austin" has value [2], and not 2. And the same goes for all other values.

More precisely, if I type:

```
print(my_dict["Houston"])
```

I get the value `[1]` and not `1`.

I know that the `csv` module converts each row/line to a list, but I don't know why the second column has brackets added to it. Why does this happen, and how can I get rid of the brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does this happen

Because you told python to use a list as the default value, i.e, `defaultdict(list)`, and you then call `.append(region_code)` on that list.

> how can I get rid of the brackets?

```
my_dict = {}
with open(my_file, newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(csv_reader)  # Skip the row containing the column headers
    for row in csv_reader:
        region_name, region_code = row[0], int(row[1])
        my_dict[region_name] = region_code
```